# SWI Prolog if statements, how do they work? Generating a simple grid

Tags: prolog

I realize I've edited out the `if` statements out of the original code which doesn't help readability and question clarity. Just skip to the answers for the explanation on how they work with a small example program.

To learn about more complex programs using `if` statements in Prolog, I'm creating a simple platformer that generates some objects and places them in a grid. First I'm trying to generate a simple 'world' with the idea of trying out generating things in prolog. The plan is to create a grid of 50 lists with 10000 items, which really shouldn't be that complicated but I can't get the `if` statements to work as I get the impression that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how they work vs how I think they work. What happens is the condition isn't met, the if statement isn't called but the whole predicate is recalled with empty variables and evaluations are not instantiated.

1. Create a simple accumulator which has an X and Y axis, and limits to
   how far they go before failing the predicate.
2. If the number of Y rows has been reached, terminate
3. Create a new [id, point(X,Y), Image] to be later filled with something
4. If X = end of the row, X is 0, else create the next point

Code:

```
generate(WorldList) :- generate_world(WorldList,0,_,10000,0,_,50).

generate_world([H|T],X,_,XEnd,Y,_,YEnd) :-
    %Y has been filled with 50 rows, end recursion
    not(Y > YEnd),
    %iterate X by 1, store in XNew
    XNew is X + 1,  
    %create a new [id,point(X,Y), Image]
    H = [XNew,point(_,_)],
    %if X has reached 10k, add 1 to Y and create a new row
    X = XEnd -> YNew is Y + 1, 
    generate_world(T,0,_,XEnd,YNew,_,YEnd);
    %continue adding items to current row Y
    generate_world(T,XNew,_,XEnd,Y,_,YEnd).
generate_world([],_,_,_,_,_,_).
```

Am I doing something blatantly wrong or how are you supposed to use prolog conditional statements and can they even be used like this at all?

The way I expect it to work is a term is evaluated, then do what is to the left of the following OR if it's true, or the right if it's false. That happens, but I don't understand why the entire predicate is called again as it also empties the variables being evaluated. My brain hurts.

What the docs say: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=-%3E/2

@damianodamiano identified the problem, `if` statements in prolog need to be surrounded by `()` tags. I'd still like a more detailed explanation of how they actually work in regards to choice points, backtracking and other Prolog specific things I might not even know about.

Comment: You need an 'else' for the comparison also (`not(By > YEnd)`). And this is not a good design. You cannot update one location in this list easily.

Comment: @TomasBy `X = XEnd -> YNew` This is the if statement that I can't get to work, the rest are regular terms.

Comment: @G_V you miss the `(` before checking `X = XEnd` and `)` after  `generate_world(T,XNew,_,XEnd,Y,_,YEnd)` to make it work. Then notice that your programs left open too many points of choice (i.e. you can press more multiple times). Check my answer.

Comment: @damianodamiano - While that does solve the grid generation beautifully, could you add something about how Prolog walks through if statements with regards to backtracking to choice points? I think I worded it poorly, but I am doing this to understand how `if` statements in Prolog behave exactly to determine whether it's worth using them. They seem to generate a LOT of calls for what they actually do. The lack of `()` grouping were indeed why they behaved erratically in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on my understanding of ISO-prolog and the other answers given, boiled down to the essence of how `if then else` works in Prolog.

The `if` predicate `->` forces evaluation its the surrounding complex terms grouped by `(` and `)`. The outer brackets identify the if-statement as `( if -> then ; else )`, where `if`,`then` and `else` are each goals in the form of terms to be evaluated, which return `yes` or `no`, also grouped by `(` and `)`. Whether `then` or `else` is called, separated by the OR operator `;`, depends on the `yes` or `no` result from the evaluated term represented by `if`. The outer groupings are strictly necessary while the inner ones are optional, BUT it's good practice in my opinion to add them anyway, given that you can nest another `if` statement as a term surrounded by `()` in the result of the first, which likely produces unwanted result and makes the code much harder to read, and any non-grouped nested `;` will identify the right side as the `else`.

Choice points are created where there are variables that can have multiple possible answers as a possible solution to the posed goal. This means within an `if`, if a term can be satisfied in multiple ways, Prolog will try to satisfy that goal as a separate goal and then use the result to determine the outcome of the surrounding term. If a goal fails, it behaves like normal code and doesn't try to satisfy the goals further right.

If a choice point is before the whole `if` statement section, the whole section will be checked again.

Example program to clarify the idea.

```
fact(a).
fact(f).

start :-
        (
            %The entire complex term is evaluated as yes
            (fact(a), write('first if'), nl) -> 
                %triggers the first line
                (write('first then'),nl) ; 
                (write('first else'),nl)        
        ),
        (
            %The entire complex term is evaluated as no
            (fact(B), write('second if'), B = b, nl) -> 
                (write('second then'),nl) ; 
                %triggers the second line
                (write('second else'),nl)
        ).
```

And the output for `?- start.`

```
first if
first then
second ifsecond ifsecond else
```

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate stops as soon as you run it because in `not(By > YEnd)`, `By` is not instantiated (note that `By` is also a singleton variable and each singleton variable is useless and can drive to errors). Here i post two implementation, the first without if statement (which personally prefer), the second with if statement (i've put `2` and `2` as bound for brevity...).

First implementation:

```
generateList(L):-
    generateWL(L,0,2,0,2).
generateWL([],0,_,Y,Y). %you can add a ! here
generateWL(L,MaxX,MaxX,R,MaxR):- %you can add a ! here
    R1 is R+1,
    generateWL(L,0,MaxX,R1,MaxR).
generateWL([H|T],X,MaxX,R,MaxR):-
    X < MaxX,
    R < MaxR,
    X1 is X+1,
    H = [X1,point(X1,R)],
    generateWL(T,X1,MaxX,R,MaxR).

?- generateList(WL).
WL = [[1, point(1, 0)], [2, point(2, 0)], [1, point(1, 1)], [2, point(2, 1)]]
false
```

If you want to prevent backtracking, just add the two cuts i've annotated.

Second implementation

```
generateList2(L):-
    generateWLIf(L,0,2,0,2).

generateWLIf([H|T],X,MaxX,R,MaxR):-
    (   X < MaxX, R < MaxR ->    
        X1 is X+1,
        H = [X1,point(X1,R)],
        generateWL(T,X1,MaxX,R,MaxR)
    ;   X = MaxX, R < MaxR ->  
        R1 is R+1,
        generateWL([H|T],0,MaxX,R1,MaxR)
    ;   R = MaxR ->  T = []).

?- generateList2(WL).
WL = [[1, point(1, 0)], [2, point(2, 0)], [1, point(1, 1)], [2, point(2, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

(Continuing from the comments)

> The way I expect [conditional statements] to work is a term is
>   evaluated, then do what is to the left of the following OR if it's
>   true, or the right if it's false. That happens, but I don't understand
>   why the entire predicate is called again as it also empties the
>   variables being evaluated.

You probably mean that it back-tracks, and the reason is that the comparison `not(Y > YEnd)` eventually fails, and there is no else-clause (and no if either).

Also, your base case makes no sense, as the list is output not input. And you want to compare against `XNew` not `X`.

```
generate(WorldList) :-
  generate_world(WorldList,1,10000,1,50).

generate_world(T,X,XEnd,Y,YEnd) :-
  ( Y = YEnd ->
    T = []
  ; T = [point(X,Y)|Rest], XNew is X + 1,
    ( XNew = XEnd -> YNew is Y + 1,
      generate_world(Rest,1,XEnd,YNew,YEnd)
    ; generate_world(Rest,XNew,XEnd,Y,YEnd) ) ).
```

This would seem to work in the sense that it does what you describe, but it is not good design. Now you have to pass this enormous list around all the time, and updating one location means deconstructing the list.

Your problem:

> I'm creating a simple platformer that generates some objects and
>   places them in a grid. First I'm trying to generate a simple 'world'
>   with the idea of trying out generating things in prolog. The plan is
>   to create a grid of 50 lists with 10000 items

is much better solved in Prolog by having a predicate `location/3` (for example) where the parameters are the coordinates and the content.

```
location(1,1,something).
location(1,2,something).
location(1,3,somethingelse).
...
```

And this predicate is created dynamically, using `assert/3`.

Comment: The second call is just to do T = []. So asserting facts and retracting them is significantly faster than keeping a list of items due to the search tree mechanism and `if` statements are generally considered a bad practice because they're inefficient?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with if-statements. Often there is a choice between two or more clauses, or one clause with if-statements, but efficiency is generally not a factor. Updating one location with `retract`+`assert` is going to be much faster than picking the list apart, yes.