# If-Then-Else Statements in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I know that the If-Then-Else structure in Prolog is

```
(Condition) -> Then block ; Else Block.
```

But the first if-then-else condition is just showing me **false** and not letting the other statements execute. What can possibly be wrong?

Here's my code:

```
calMedian(X,Y,Z) :-

    X > Y ->  
    (       
        Temp is X, X is Y, Y is Temp
    ;   X is X, Y is Y
    ),

    Y > Z ->  
    (   
        Temp is Y, Y is Z, Z is Temp
    ;   Y is Y, Z is Z
    ),

    X > Z ->  
    (   
        Temp is X, X is Z, Z is Temp
    ;   X is X, Z is Z
    ),

    write('Median is : '),writeln(Y).
```

I just placed some lines like `X is X, Y is Y` because it was asking for something in the else block.

Comment: You cannot change the value of a variable in Prolog. Read the next page or two of your book/documentation and try again. Prolog really is different.

Comment: I just tried the same by using temporary variables but the error stays the same.

Comment: Please note the priority of operators! You write `( a -> ( b ; c ))` which is different to `(a -> b ; c)`! So if-then-else has as principal functor `(;)/2` and not `(->)/2`!

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that the whole statement is a SINGLE term to Prolog, so you need to present it as such by surrounding it with `()` grouping brackets. `(if -> then ; else), another_call, (if -> then ; else)` where each block is a separate group of goals to be satisfied.

Comment: I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736826/swi-prolog-if-statements-how-do-they-work-generating-a-simple-grid) a while back, which explains the if-then-else construction in Prolog